# Handling imploded values from a find operation in the controller

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm sure someone here can help me. First off a little background on what I'm doing. I am basically building a social networking site, for easy understanding basically call it a mock of everyone's favorite, Facebook.

Currently everything is working fine with the exception of one thing. That one thing is displaying all my friends posts on the "wall". I can get my posts and I can also get the posts of the person with the lowest ID from both my requested friends and from those friends that requested me.

So for instance, let's say I am User A and there is User B, User C, User D and User E. I login and request User B and User C, which they both approve. Let's assume User D and User E request me and I approve both of them. So Now I (User A) am friends with Users B, C, D and E. I requested B and C, D and E requested me. For the sake of this example let's assume the ID's of these user go in order; 1 being me (A), through 5 being E.

When the "wall" populates I get my posts, which should be expected, but I only get the posts from User B (which I requested) and User D (which requested me). User's C and E's posts don't show because their ID's are after B and D's...

Now to the code... the models involved are User, Friendship and WallPost. My users_controller has the following find operations in the profile() function.

```
   $friends_to = $this->Friendship->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => array('Friendship.pending' => 1, 'Friendship.approved' => 1, 'UserTo.id' => $id),
          'fields' => array('Friendship.user_from')
        )
    );  
    $friends_to_ids = implode(',', Set::extract($friends_to, '{n}.Friendship.user_from'));

    $friends_from = $this->Friendship->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => array('Friendship.pending' => 1, 'Friendship.approved' => 1, 'UserFrom.id' => $id),
          'fields' => array('Friendship.user_to')
        )
    );
    $friends_from_ids = implode(',', Set::extract($friends_from, '{n}.Friendship.user_to'));

    $post_conditions =  array(
        'OR' => array(
            array('WallPost.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
            array('WallPost.user_id' => $friends_to_ids),
            array('WallPost.user_id' => $friends_from_ids)
        ),
    );
    $posts = $this->WallPost->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => $post_conditions,
          'order' => array('WallPost.created' => 'desc')
        )
    );
    $this -> set ('posts', $posts);
```

In context to the example I gave above this would return the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT `WallPost`.`id`, `WallPost`.`user_id`, `WallPost`.`content`, `WallPost`.`created`, `WallPost`.`modified`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`group_id`, `User`.`confirmed`, `User`.`confirm_code`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `wall_posts` AS `WallPost` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`WallPost`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE ((`WallPost`.`user_id` = 1) OR (`WallPost`.`user_id` = '2,3') OR (`WallPost`.`user_id` = '4,5')) ORDER BY `WallPost`.`created` desc
```

So the ID's are there but only displaying the following. (`WallPost`.`user_id` = 1), User with the ID of 1. (`WallPost`.`user_id` = '2,3'), Only User ID 2 is displaying. (`WallPost`.`user_id` = '4,5'), Only User ID 4 is displaying.

What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't this displaying results from all these users? Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Quick UPDATE: I restructured my query so it's a bit different but returning the same thing.

```
SELECT `WallPost`.`id`, `WallPost`.`user_id`, `WallPost`.`content`, `WallPost`.`created`, `WallPost`.`modified`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`group_id`, `User`.`confirmed`, `User`.`confirm_code`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `wall_posts` AS `WallPost` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`WallPost`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `WallPost`.`user_id` IN (1, '2,3', '4,5') ORDER BY `WallPost`.`created` desc
```

After a bit more research it appears as if it is viewing '2,3' and '4,5' as a strings when it should be viewing them as everything as IN (1,2,3,4,5). How I can fix this is failing to come to me, again any help would be appreciated.

**Thanks for the help guys that was the correct answer. Now here's my next small issue on this probelm.**

So whats being pulled from the DB is being queried against 3 things, my user id, and the 2 arrays that contain the requested and approved friends id's and the id's of the friends that have requested and been approved by me. Using the same techniques given in the solution below I now have.

```
$friends_tos = $this->Friendship->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => array('Friendship.pending' => 1, 'Friendship.approved' => 1, 'UserTo.id' => $id),
          'fields' => array('Friendship.user_from'), //array of field names
        )
    );  
    $friends_to_ids = Set::extract($friends_tos, '{n}.Friendship.user_from');

    $friends_froms = $this->Friendship->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => array('Friendship.pending' => 1, 'Friendship.approved' => 1, 'UserFrom.id' => $id),
          'fields' => array('Friendship.user_to'), //array of field names
        )
    );
    $friends_from_ids = Set::extract($friends_froms, '{n}.Friendship.user_to');
```

Which give me $friends_to_ids = (2,3) and $friends_from)ids = (4,5), I then use the following `$aMerge = array_merge($friends_to_ids, $friends_from_ids);` to combine them which gives me $aMerge = (2,3,4,5), which is great.

However using this as my find condition:

```
$post_conditions =  array(
        'OR' => array(
            'WallPost.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
            'WallPost.user_id' => $aMerge
        ),
    );
```

Only returns the values of $aMerge and completely skips the value of my user ID. I have tried multiple ways of restructuring this find condition, but to no avail. I'm sure I'm missing something small as that is what it usually is, but I'm drawing blanks...

Make sure you answer where I can mark it...

Comment: The conditions shouldn't be in the format `'field' => '2,3'` but `'field' => array(2,3)`, so you only need to use the result of `Set::extract` without imploding it.

Comment: @ori is right. By passing an array, Cake generates an `IN` statement in the SQL.

Comment: @ori: Better make that into an answer before someone else does. Like me for example ;)

Comment: Awesome guys thank you so much, it so happens that I figured that out before coming back here to check up on the answer and that is exactly what I did. However I have a new issue related to this. Which is explained above after the bold text. P.S. I'm new here, but aren't you supposed to answer this in an area that I can give someone credit for the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

OK so maybe it's not the cleanest way, but I had a thought, tried it and it worked. If anyone has a simpler and cleaner solution I would greatly appreciate knowing what it is.

So here's what I did. Following the same flow as finding the friends I found myself, using a find 'all' and limiting the return to 1. Then extracting that ID in the form of an array, even though it's a single value.

```
$me = $this->User->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
          'fields' => array('User.id'),
          'limit' => 1,
        )
    );
    $my_id = Set::extract($me, '{n}.User.id');
```

I then added that to the array_merge:

```
$aMerge = array_merge($my_id, $friends_to_ids, $friends_from_ids);
```

Then when using the $aMerge as my find condition for the "wall" post I got the return (1,2,3,4,5) which is exactly what I needed. Again thx all for the help and move your answer so I can give your credit...